# Sort arraylist containing hashmaps of strings?

Tags: java, android

I have an `ArrayList` which contains some `HashMap<String,String>`. Each `HashMap` contains two pairs of numbers and two pairs of names all in string format. It's like this:

`h1:<"num1","20"> <"num2","17"> <"name1","x"> <"name2","y">`.

I want to sort such `ArrayList` by this rule:

`(h1.num1 + h1.num2) > (h2.num1 + h2.num2)`

and if they're `equal then comparison` will be applied to just `(h1.num1 > h2.num1)`.

But as `num1` and `num2` are strings, i can't do such comparison. By the way if i cast them to int, then i face a generic error. And finally if i remove the generic,

I face a **syntax error** at return statement: `cannot cast from File to int.` Any idea?

In the code below the error is at `return` statement:

```
private void calcMedia() {
        mediaStatsDetailsArrayList.addAll(app.mediaArrayList);
        Collections.sort(mediaStatsDetailsArrayList, new Comparator <HashMap<String, String>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(HashMap h1, HashMap h2) {
                int sum1 = (Integer.parseInt((String) h1.get("noOfLikes")) + Integer.parseInt((String) h1.get("noOfComments")));
                h1.put("sum", sum1);
                int sum2 = (Integer.parseInt((String) h2.get("noOfLikes")) + Integer.parseInt((String) h2.get("noOfComments")));
                h2.put("sum", sum2);
                if (sum1 == sum2)
                    return ((Object) h1.get("noOfLikes")).compareTo((Object) h2.get("noOfLikes"));
                return ((Object) h1.get("sum")).compareTo((Object) h2.get("sum"));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: return is for compare().

Comment: It is not a good idea to modify your parameters whilst evaluating `compare`. If you need to calculate the `sum` property and store it in the map, do this by iterating the list before sorting.

Comment: Casting to File automatically is done when i remove generics @Daniel Nugent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the code like below solved my problem:

```
Collections.sort(mediaStatsDetailsArrayList, new Comparator <HashMap<String, String>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(HashMap h1, HashMap h2) {
                int likes1 = Integer.parseInt((String) h1.get("noOfLikes"));
                int sum1 = (Integer.parseInt((String) h1.get("noOfLikes")) + Integer.parseInt((String) h1.get("noOfComments")));
                h1.put("likes", likes1);
                h1.put("sum", sum1);
                int likes2 = Integer.parseInt((String) h2.get("noOfLikes"));
                int sum2 = (Integer.parseInt((String) h2.get("noOfLikes")) + Integer.parseInt((String) h2.get("noOfComments")));
                h2.put("likes", likes2);
                h2.put("sum", sum2);
                if (sum1 == sum2)
                    return ((Integer) h1.get("likes")).compareTo((Integer) h2.get("likes"));
                return ((Integer) h1.get("sum")).compareTo((Integer) h2.get("sum"));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) implementation and put your logic in `compareTo()` to sort the hashmaps.

As for your second part, Strings have a `compareTo()` which lets you compare one string to another.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
hmap.put("num1", "\"20\"");
hmap.put("num2", "17");
hmap.put("name1", "\"x\"");
hmap.put("name2", "y");

System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
Set set = hmap.entrySet();
Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
    System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
    System.out.println(me.getValue());
}
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(hmap);
System.out.println("After Sorting:");
Set set2 = map.entrySet();
Iterator iterator2 = set2.iterator();
while(iterator2.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry me2 = (Map.Entry)iterator2.next();
    System.out.print(me2.getKey() + ": ");
    System.out.println(me2.getValue());
}
```